# Javascript to take to home page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to correct something in a PHP project. 
I have two pages, `home.php` and `page1.php`. 
I have separately a `header.php` which is rendered in both pages (`home.php` and `page1.php`).

[image]

The problem is that when I am in page1.PHP, the links from the header are not working. It should go to the home page and scroll to clicked section.

Can you please help me how to make it work in javascript or jquery if I click on a navigation button to take me to a home page.

In home page if I click on a navigation button, it will scroll to desired section. This problem is resolved like this in 'header.php':

```
jQuery('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = jQuery(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : jQuery('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');

      var calculatedHeight = jQuery(".tip-top.fixed").length ? 120 : 230;
      if (target.length) {
        jQuery('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - calculatedHeight
        }, 700);
        return false;
      }
    }
});
```

These are the sections:

```
    <ul class="nav list-inline visible-lg visible-md clearfix pull-right nav-pills main-menu">
         <li><a href="#panel-two">Clients</a></li>
         <li><a href="#panel-three">Case studies</a></li>
         <li><a href="#panel-for">Capabilities</a></li>
         <li><a href="#panel-nine">Team</a></li>
         <li><a href="#footer-container-1">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
```

When I am in the `page1.php` and I click on a navigation link, in the URL appears the section name where it should take me:

```
http://localhost/ppi/teszt/#panel-nine
```

Can you please help me how to achieve this?

Comment: Update your links like this <li><a href="home.php#panel-nine">Team</a></li>

Comment: It's not working like this, because like this the link will be: http://localhost/ppi/teszt/home.php#panel-nine, and in home page it should be:http://localhost/ppi/#panel-for to take me to the pane for section

Comment: At home page it will still take you to the panel

Comment: Yes, it would take me to the panel, but it not takes me to home page.

Comment: But when you'll click on the click from home page. so you will be still at homepage?

Comment: Yes, it will remain on home page on that case

Comment: so what's the problem like If you're at page1.php and click on link it will take you to home.php#panel-nine. and if you're at home page it will still take you there.

Comment: The problem is that if I use like this: <a href="home.php#panel-nine"...>, the link will be localhost/ppi/teszt/home.php#panel-nine, and I got 404 page error. The link should be only: localhost/ppi/#panel-nine. If I use like this: <li><a href="/ppi/#panel-nine">Team</a></li> it is ok, but I don;t know if on live I will have that /ppi/ tag.